# Android notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a list which is filled with a custom `ArrayAdapter`.

I want to update a progress bar every second, so I am trying to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` in order to repaint the list but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How are you updating the `List` data structure that is feeding `ArrayAdapter`?

Please see my answer here: [notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426)

for issues regarding `ArrayAdapters` and updating the `List` that holds data for `notifyDataSetChanged` to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not calling this from the main thread try having the main thread call this function.  That is usually the problem when notifyDataSetChanged isn't updating the actual screen contents.

Comment: I believe so, whenever i have to update my graphics form a thread I post a message to a handler that I create in my main view.

Comment: please provide an example of how to call it from the main thread

Answer (score 0):

I probably have the answer. Try this:

```
((BaseAdapter) arrayAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I had the same problem and this was the solution for mine :)