# Refresh ArrayList Android application

Tags: java, android, arraylist

can anyone tell me how can I use `notifyDataSetChanged();` function when I want to refresh my arrylist in a activity when myadapter extends baseAdapter !!!

thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when ever data of your array is changed you can call     `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
will refresh the data of your **listview**.

Comment: have been tried that and got this error: The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListView !!

Comment: I'm trying now .. if it works ill mark this answer .. thanks for ur quick response

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
lviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here you can find details.

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345875/android-notifydatasetchanged)

Comment: have been tried that and got this error: The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListView !!

Comment: have you extend ListActivity class.?

Comment: try this ((BaseAdapter) lview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I tried it before but it didn't work .. i'm trying now with other solution thanks for ur quick response

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426