# Android auto refresh when new data inserted into listview

Tags: android, mysql, database, listview, refresh

I've been developing android application.
I have back end ( Web Application ) and front end ( Android Application ).

In my application, it has category that contain a bunch of list of items.
When i choose a category, it will call a task that use to call all data in DB.
Once task complete call all data, it'll direct to activity.
And activity will show all data in a ListView.

Now, for example i insert a new data from back end ( Web ).
Let just say i insert a new row contain a boxing into sport category.
So, in DB it'll have boxing in table sport.

And in my android application, i'm currently in sport category.
So, when boxing inserted into new DB, it should have auto refresh and show me boxing in the list.

But how do i do it when the task only run once when i click a category in category list ?
i want to compare the total of data in DB and the data that shown in android application.
When the data isn't the same, it'll call the task again.

This is the code where i want my application to refresh

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if(mWifi.isConnected()) 
    {
        refresh = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Do something
                handler.postDelayed(refresh, 1000);
            }
        };
        handler.post(refresh);

        /*gridArray = new ArrayList<FlipItem>();
        adapter = new PackageListItemAdapter(this, this, gridArray);        
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/

    }
    else
    {
        refresh = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Do something
                handler.postDelayed(refresh, 60000);
            }
        };
        handler.post(refresh);
        /*gridArray = new ArrayList<FlipItem>();
        adapter = new PackageListItemAdapter(this, this, gridArray);        
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
    }
```

The code where i comment there, make my list only show about 9 where i have 15 items on DB.
That's why i comment that line

Comment: post your code for more help?

Comment: Use CursorLoader for implementing this functionality.

Comment: u should check push notification , as there should be a way to notify your mobile app from web app, and then you should use loaders to load data asynchronously !!

Comment: @Boopathi that's the code where i want to implement auto refresh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on your Adapter.

Some additional specifics on how/when to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` can be viewed in this [Google I/O video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=17m38s).

Use a `Handler` and its `postDelayed` method to invalidate the list's adapter as follows:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler()
handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.postDelayed( this, 60 * 1000 );
    }
}, 60 * 1000 );
```

You must only update UI in the main (UI) thread.

By creating the handler in the main thread, you ensure that everything you post to the handler is run in the main thread also.

```
try
                {
                    validat_user(receivedName);
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            todoItems.clear();
                            //alertDialog.cancel();
                            validat_user(receivedName);
                            handler.postDelayed( this, 60 * 1000 );
                        }
                    }, 60 * 1000 );


                }

                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    display("Network error.\nPlease check with your network settings.");
                }
```

First `validate user` is first time load the data ,after using handler i can update the values every one minute

my full code is below

```
package com.example.employeeinduction;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class pdf extends Activity
{

    ImageView iv;
    public boolean connect=false,logged=false;
    public String db_select;
    ListView l1;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    String mPwd,UName1="Success",UName,ret,receivedName;
    public Iterator<String> itr;
    //private String SERVICE_URL = "http://61.12.7.197:8080/pdf";
    //private String SERVICE_URL1 = "http://61.12.7.197:8080/url";
    //private final String SERVICE_URL = "http://10.54.3.208:8080/Employee/person/pdf";
    //private final String SERVICE_URL1 = "http://10.54.3.208:8080/Employee/person/url";
    private final String SERVICE_URL = Urlmanager.Address+"pdf";
    private final String SERVICE_URL1 = Urlmanager.Address+"url";
    private final String TAG = "Pdf";
    ArrayList<String> todoItems;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    public List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public ListView mDrawerList;
    //public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // NavigationDrawer title "Nasdaq" in this example
    public CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    //  App title "Navigation Drawer" in this example 
    public CharSequence mTitle;

    // slider menu items details 
    public String[] navMenuTitles=null;
    public TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    public ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    public NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sliding_project);
         iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        l1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // getting items of slider from array
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // getting Navigation drawer icons from res 
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();


        // list item in slider at 1 Home Nasdaq details
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // list item in slider at 2 Facebook details
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // list item in slider at 3 Google details
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // list item in slider at 4 Apple details


        // Recycle array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting list adapter for Navigation Drawer
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
              displayView(0);
        }

          iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext(), v);

                    /** Adding menu items to the popumenu */
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, popup.getMenu());

                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                            switch (item.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.Home:
                                Intent a = new Intent(pdf.this,Design_Activity.class);
                                startActivity(a);
                                //Projects_Accel.this.finish();
                            //  return true;
                                break;
                            case R.id.Logout:
                                /*Intent z = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                                z.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(z);
                                this.finish();*/
                                Intent z = new Intent(pdf.this,MainActivity.class);
                                z.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
                                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(z);
                                pdf.this.finish();
                            //  return true;
                                break;
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                        popup.show();
                }
            });

             todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_row,R.id.title,todoItems);
                l1.setAdapter(aa);
                todoItems.clear();
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                receivedName = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("PROJECT");
                cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
                isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                if(isInternetPresent)
                {
                try
                {
                    validat_user(receivedName);
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            todoItems.clear();
                            //alertDialog.cancel();
                            validat_user(receivedName);
                            handler.postDelayed( this, 60 * 1000 );
                        }
                    }, 60 * 1000 );


                }

                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    display("Network error.\nPlease check with your network settings.");
                }
                }
                else
                {
                    display("No Internet Connection..");
                }

                l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                     String name=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                     /*Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Webview.class);
                      i.putExtra("USERNAME", name);
                      startActivity(i);*/
                     cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
                        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                     if(isInternetPresent)
                        {
                     try
                        {
                            validat_user1(receivedName,name);

                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            display("Network error.\nPlease check with your network settings.");

                        }

                        }
                     else
                        {
                            display("No Internet Connection..");
                        }
                    }
                });

             }      
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // display view for selected item
    displayView(position);
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
//setMenuBackground();
return true;
}


/*@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//  title/icon
if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
    return true;
}
// Handle action bar actions click
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.action_settings:
    return true;
default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}*/

//called when invalidateOptionsMenu() invoke 

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// if Navigation drawer is opened, hide the action items
//boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
//menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
// update the main content with called Fragment
switch (position) {

case 1:
    //fragment = new Fragment2Profile();
    Intent i = new Intent(pdf.this,Design_Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    pdf.this.finish();
    break;
case 2:
    //fragment = new Fragment3Logout();
    Intent z = new Intent(pdf.this,MainActivity.class);
    z.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(z);
        pdf.this.finish();
    break;

default:
    break;
}



}




        public void display(String msg) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(pdf.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        private void validat_user(String st)
        {

            WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK, this, "");

           wst.addNameValuePair1("TABLE_NAME", st);
           // wst.addNameValuePair("Emp_PWD", stg2);
           // db_select=stg1;
            //display("I am");
            wst.execute(new String[] { SERVICE_URL });
            //display(SERVICE_URL);

        }
        private void validat_user1(String stg1,String stg2)
        {
            db_select=stg1;
            WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK, this, "Loading...");

            wst.addNameValuePair1("PDF_NAME", stg1);
            wst.addNameValuePair1("TABLE_NAME1", stg2);
            wst.execute(new String[] { SERVICE_URL1 });

        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void no_net()
        {
            display( "No Network Connection");
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(pdf.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
            alertDialog.setMessage("You don't have internet connection.\nElse please check the Internet Connection Settings.");
            //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.error_info);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {   
                    alertDialog.cancel();
                    pdf.this.finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setButton2("Use Local DataBase", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    display( "Accessing local DataBase.....");
                    alertDialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }

        private class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

            public static final int POST_TASK = 1;

            private static final String TAG = "WebServiceTask";

            // connection timeout, in milliseconds (waiting to connect)
            private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 12000;

            // socket timeout, in milliseconds (waiting for data)
            private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 12000;

            private int taskType = POST_TASK;
            private Context mContext = null;
            private String processMessage = "Processing...";

            private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            private ProgressDialog pDlg = null;

            public WebServiceTask(int taskType, Context mContext, String processMessage) {

                this.taskType = taskType;
                this.mContext = mContext;
                this.processMessage = processMessage;
            }

            public void addNameValuePair1(String name, String value) {

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            private void showProgressDialog() {

                pDlg = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                pDlg.setMessage(processMessage);
                pDlg.setProgressDrawable(mContext.getWallpaper());
                pDlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                pDlg.setCancelable(false);
                pDlg.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                showProgressDialog();

            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

                String url = urls[0];
                String result = "";

                HttpResponse response = doResponse(url);

                if (response == null) {
                    return result;
                } else {

                    try {

                        result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                    }

                }

                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

                handleResponse(response);
                pDlg.dismiss();

            }


            // Establish connection and socket (data retrieval) timeouts
            private HttpParams getHttpParams() {

                HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();

                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, CONN_TIMEOUT);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

                return htpp;
            }

            private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {

                // Use our connection and data timeouts as parameters for our
                // DefaultHttpClient
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());

                HttpResponse response = null;

                try {
                    switch (taskType) {

                    case POST_TASK:
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                        // Add parameters
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    display("Remote DataBase can not be connected.\nPlease check network connection.");

                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                    return null;

                }

                return response;
            }

            private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

                String line = "";
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

                // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                try {
                    // Read response until the end
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        total.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                }

                // Return full string
                return total.toString();
            }

        }
        public void handleResponse(String response) 
        {    //display("JSON responce is : "+response);
            if(!response.equals(""))
            {
           try {

                JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(response);


                      int UName = jso.getInt("status1");

                      if(UName==1)
                      {
                            String status = jso.getString("reps1");
                            ret=status.substring(12,status.length()-2);
                            todoItems.add(0, ret);
                            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      }
                      else if(UName==-1)
                      {
                          String status = jso.getString("status");
                          //ret=status.substring(12,status.length()-2);
                          //display(status);
                            Intent intObj=new Intent(pdf.this,Webview.class);
                             intObj.putExtra("USERNAME",status);
                            startActivity(intObj);
                      }
                      else if(UName>1)
                      {
//                       int count=Integer.parseInt(UName);
//                       display("Number of Projects have been handling in AFL right now: "+count);
                        list1=new ArrayList<String>();

                        JSONArray array=jso.getJSONArray("reps1");
                        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                        {
                            list1.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("pdfName"));

                        }Collections.sort(list1);
                        Collections.reverse(list1);
                        itr=list1.iterator();
                        while(itr.hasNext())
                        {
                             //str1=itr.next()+"\n";
                            todoItems.add(0, itr.next().toString());
                            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        //tv1.setText(str1);


                      }  
                      else
                      {
                          final Context context = this;
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                context);

                            // set title
                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("");

                            // set dialog message
                            alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage("Records unavailable for this project!")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Exit",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                        // current activity
                                        pdf.this.finish();
                                    }
                                  });

                                // create alert dialog
                                alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                                // show it
                                alertDialog.show();
                      }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                return;
            }
            }
            else
            {
                display("unable to reach the server");
            }


        }



        /**
         * Slider menu item click listener
         * */
        /*private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
                ListView.OnItemClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // display view for selected item
                displayView(position);
            }
        }


        private void displayView(int position) {
            // update the main content with called Fragment
        //  Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
            //  fragment = new Fragment1User();
                break;
            case 1:
            //  fragment = new Fragment2Profile();
                break;
            case 2:
            //  fragment = new Fragment3Logout();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }*/


}
```

Comment: How to compare data from DB and the data that already shown in page ?

Comment: It doesn't update a new data in Listview.
No matter how many time i try to add a new row in table sport.
It won't appear. Because ItemListTask is already stopping get data from DB. @Boopathi

Comment: @ChristSamuel now i update my code,go through that,hadlers works fine

Answer (score 0):

just use this code `namelistview".invalidateViews();`

works well for me

Answer (score -2):

Use `notifyDataSetChanged` for Refresh your list, can refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345875/android-notifydatasetchanged)

Comment: I already try to use notifyDataSetChanged, but only a few data shown on page. I have 15 data, it only show 9 data.

Comment: I think your WS should return you only updated\newly inserted data, and app will require  to process those data only. 
Else You can have loop to your record set, and can manually check is there any changes or not. and based on that can re fresh list.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() is not going to work here , first web app should tell the mobile app that a new row has been inserted !!