# Xamarin.Android how to auto update RecyclerView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Following [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/recyclerview-highly-optimized-collections-for-android-apps/) article I created a simple application that displays a list. The list I get from a web service (.asmx web service).

I want to auto update `RecyclerView` every 5 seconds and I have no idea how to do it.

In WinForms I would have used the Timer component, but I don't know how this works in Xamarin.

***MainActivity.cs***

```
[Activity(Label = "CibMonitor", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
        ConnectionItemsAdapter adapter;
        ConnectionItem[] connectionItems;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            var ci = new ConnectionItem();

            //Get list from web service
            connectionItems = ci.GetList().ToArray();

            //Setup RecyclerView
            adapter = new ConnectionItemsAdapter(this, connectionItems);

            recyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

            recyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);

            ChangedData();
        }
    }
```

***Update***
I created new method in activity class as York Shen suggested

```
void ChangedData()
{
    Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        var newData = ConnectionItem.GetList();
        adapter.RefreshItems(newData);
        ChangedData();
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

This is my update method in adapter class:

```
public void RefreshItems(List<ConnectionItem> newItems)
{
    items.Clear();
    items = newItems;
    NotifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

my app stops working, no exception only this message:[image]

Comment: i tried `notifyDataSetChanged()` method in adapter but not worked

Comment: I'd use a `Handler` for your task.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23124493/3373603) handler? can you show how to write this in c#?

Comment: alittle googling will do the trick. Trust me, it's easy. Search for `android handler xamarin`

Comment: Sorry for late, it seems that this is a ANR, you can't do too much work in Main thread. Can you share a demo about this? I don't know what you did in the Main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Task` which can help you update recyclerView every 5 seconds:

```
void ChangedData()
    {
        Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
           adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
           ChangedData();//This is for repeate every 5s.
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry for late reply, calling the `ChangedData()` in `Task.Delay()` can resolve the repeate problem. You can `invoke` the `ChangedData()` in `OnCreate()` method. Hope this can help you. : )

Comment: i need to invoke `ChangedData()` method in `OnCreate()` method?

Comment: ChangedData() executes only once, my app freezed and i get message `Myapp isn't responding do you want to close it`

Comment: @user3373603, Sorry for late, I had add the solution in my answer. : )